# When browsing a specific network share remotely, Windows Explorer continuously jumps back to the parent folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, network-shares

I am accessing a specific network path on another domain. It looks something like this:

> \\CoputerName.OtherDomain.in\c$\Inetpub\Testing\Website\

In under 30 seconds, I am automatically jumped back to

> \\CoputerName.OtherDomain.in\c$\Inetpub\Testing\

In less time it then jumps back to

> \\CoputerName.OtherDomain.in\c$\Inetpub\

Then it jumps back to c$ for its final resting place.

> \\CoputerName.OtherDomain.in\c$\

At first I thought this had to with a faulty keyboard, but this behaviour also occurs when the window does not have focus. It's as if windows thinks that the folder no longer exists (as in someone else has deleted or moved it).

This behaviour is not specific to my PC either, it occurs from other machines in the office.

Edit: It looks like this issue only occurs from other Windows 7 machines. There are no issues accessing the path from XP.

Comment: It does look like the folder is being removed. Maybe you are being disconnected... Is there a timeout on the server you are connecting to?

Comment: It might be worth looking to see if there are subtle tells in the networking. Have you tried wiresharking to see if one of the NICs is misbehaving?

Comment: What is known about the machine hosting the network folder you are trying to browse?

Comment: Are you wired or wireless? It sounds to me something in network connection between you and the file server bugs, ie. disconnects and then immediately reconnects you.

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling the [Network Location Awareness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264321%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) service. It sends updates to various applications (including Windows Explorer) when it detects changing network conditions. If it works, you should investigate what is causing NLA to trigger. Perhaps you have a LAN and wireless connection active at the same time.