# Windows 10 File Explorer keeps navigating to the parent folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I am working within a network share mapped to a drive letter and every time I save a file, it navigates back to the parent folder.  Specifically, I am working with Microsoft Publisher files.  This is rather irritating.  As soon as I save a file within Publisher, the opened folder in File Explorer jumps to the parent folder causing me to have to double-click the folder again to access the files.

It's similar to this question:  [When browsing a specific network share remotely, Windows Explorer continuously jumps back to the parent folder](https://superuser.com/questions/288332/when-browsing-a-specific-network-share-remotely-windows-explorer-continuously-j)

Except it does not recursively navigate to the parent; it only does this once, and it does it precisely when I save a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug more people seem to have. I solved it by deactivating the automatic colour in the Personalization Settings and also the Wallpaper Slideshow. Both of them seem to cause the explorer to do a kind of refresh, which throws you back to the top of the list or even to the parent folder.

I found this solution here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/win10-file-explorer-jumps-to-top-of-folder/5ade28a8-002e-4cf8-8a66-f082235b7260?page=1